# How to count the number of occurrences of a particular word in a MySQL blob text?

Tags: mysql, sql, text, blob

I have stored the contents of a text file in a MySQL table as a blob. I want to count the number of occurrences of a particular word from that text.

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: what is the 'word' you want to search. what is the field name of the blob, give the table structure please

Comment: the word is 'lumia', field name of blob is 'file' and table name is 'documents'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SET @searchthis="lumia"; 
SELECT  CAST((LENGTH(`documents`.`file`) - 
              LENGTH(REPLACE(`documents`.`file`, @searchthis, ""))) /
              LENGTH(@searchthis) AS UNSIGNED
            ) AS searchthis_count
    FROM  documents ;
```

Comment: @Sajith: Beware that this can produce erroneous results if `@searchthis` and `documents.file` are in different character sets: one should use `CHAR_LENGTH()` instead of `LENGTH()` for these operations.

Comment: Pls help me with this question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454938/counting-the-number-of-rows-that-have-a-particular-word-in-a-column-of-blob-data