# Counting the number of rows that have a particular word in a column of blob data type in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, string, text, blob

I have a table like this in mysql. The datatype of column 'file' is blob. I need to count the number of rows which have the word 'lumia' in column 'file' and 'display' in column 'attribute'. That is, here the rows 1 and 3. so the output has to be 2. How can i do that in mysql?

The multiple occurrence of the word lumia in 3rd row need not be counted twice.

```
  +------+----------------------------+------------+
  | slno | file                       | attribute  | 
  +------+----------------------------+------------+
  |    1 | 5inch 8mp lumia snapdragon | display    |
  |
  |    2 | 8mp galaxy samsung android | camera     | 
  |
  |    3 | nokia lumia red lumia      | display    |
  |
  |    4 | black samsung 8mp android  | camera     |
  |
  |    5 | lumia windows 8mp red      | model      |
```

Comment: You *could* match against a regular expression with MySQL's [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) operator, e.g. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE file REGEXP '[[:<:]]lumia[[:>:]]' AND attribute = 'display'`—but the filter on `file` will be case sensitive (since the column is a `BLOB` type, which it probably shouldn't be), is not sargable and won't scale well.  You might fare better looking into [full-text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-search.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what is stated in [How to count the number of occurrences of a particular word in a MySQL blob text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454011/how-to-count-the-number-of-occurrence-of-a-particular-word-in-mysql-blob-text)

If you need to get the sum try something like this

```
SELECT SUM(IF(LOCATE(@searchthis, file),1,0)) AS Count_Sum FROM  `documents`;
```

Excluding the `SUM()` the results are like below as stated in condition "The multiple occurrence of the word lumia in 3rd row need not be counted twice"

[image]